# Forms authentication in ssrs 2008 r2?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Can anybody explain the detailed step by step procedure for form authentication in sql reporting services 2008 r2 .I am new to ssrs ,I need details about how to configure in rsreportserver,web.config files and how to  write coding for authentication for ssrs .Is there any special procedure for ssrs  forms authentication and how to verify in C# code  and where to redirect ?

Answer (score 1):

See these links for some examples & other information from Microsoft:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281383.aspx

http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008R2%21Security%20Extension%20Sample

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675943/SSRS-Forms-Authentication

The high level summary is:

- Create custom authentication process (login form, credential source, backend code to wire it all together)
- Extend LogonUser() method of SSRS webservice
- Modify configs to expect forms auth, and allow your custom code to run within the app pool

I've done this a few times now, and honestly, it's easier than it sounds.

Comment: after made the configuration changes for forms authentication when opening the report server url  i got follwing error "
    The report server encountered an unhandled exception in HttpApplication. (rsUnhandledHttpApplicationError) . so can u please explain why this happend and whats the solution for this?
        File does not exist"

Comment: Open the most recent log file in the "logfiles" folder (should be in the Reporting Services installation directory).  There should be a more detailed error message in there - can you post that?