# SSRS - User Permissions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report used by many users from different regions.

1. Is it possible to show/hide information based on region without
   using parameters - we are using a single report?
2. Is it possible to give report permissions to users who are outside
   of network(Company)?

Answer (score 2):

Without using parameters how do you intend deciding which information to hide or show?

1. If (big IF because you haven't said why you cannot use parameters) what you want to do is possible then you are going to
   have to
2. Create separate folders for each class of user.
3. Set the permissions on those folders so that they can only see their
   own folder.
4. Put a **copy** of the report in the folder.
5. Have a hidden parameter which passes the class of user into the
   report **OR**
6. Pass in the current windows authenticated user into the report and
   report on class of user from the windows login.

In answer to your second question - Yes- you will need to set up [Forms Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198735/forms-authentication-in-ssrs-2008-r2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer..one quick question is instead of different folders can we have all reports in one folder?..If folder contains 3 same reports  i want to give permissions to 3 different regions..is it possible?,,,Thanks for your help

Comment: You are going to upload the same report into the same folder three times with different names? Try it - but it is going to be messy!

Comment: Yeah exactly with different names..correct its going to messy ..but just want to know it is possible or not..Thank You For Your Help :)